# Extracting and manipulating data from excel worksheet with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

**Scenario:** I am trying to come up with a python code that reads all the workbooks in a given folder, gets the data of each and puts it to a single data frame (each workbook becomes a dataframe, so I can manipulate them individually).

**Issue1:** With this code, even though I am using the proper path and file types, I keep getting the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-3-2a450c707fbe>", line 14, in <module>
f = open(file,'r')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '(1)Copy of 
Preisanfrage_17112016.xlsx'
```

**Issue2:** The reason for me to create different data frames is that each workbook has an individual format (rows are my identifiers and columns are dates). My problem is that some of these workbooks have data on a sheet named "Closing", or "Opening" or the name is not specified. So I will try to configure each data frame individually and them join them afterwards.

**Issue3:** Considering the final output once the data frame data is already unified, my objective is to output them in a format like:

```
date 1    identifier 1    value
date 1    identifier 2    value
date 1    identifier 3    value
date 1    identifier 4    value
date 2    identifier 1    value
date 2    identifier 4    value
date 2    identifier 5    value
```

**Obs1:** For the output, not all dates have the same array of identifiers.

**Question 1:** Any ideas why the code is yielding this error? Is there a better way to extract data from excel?

**Question 2:** Is it possible to create a unique dataframe for each worksheet? Is this a good practice?

**Question 3:** Can I do this type of output using a loop? Is this a good practice?

**Obs2:** I don't know how relevant this is, but I am using Python 3.6 with Anaconda.

**Code so far:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob, os
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib as mpl


directory = os.path.join("C:\\","Users\\Dgms\\Desktop\\final 2")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
for file in files:
    print(file)
    f = open(file,'r')
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think you do not need your open. And I would store them in a list. you can either use `pd.concat(list_of_dfs)` or some manual changes.

```
list_of_dfs = []
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        f = os.path.join(root, file)
        print(f)
        list_of_dfs .append(pd.read_excel(f))
```

or using `glob`:

```
import glob
list_of_dfs = []
for file in glob.iglob(directory + '*.xlsx')
    print(file)
    list_of_dfs .append(pd.read_excel(file))
```

or as jackie suggests you can read specific sheets `list_of_dfs.append(pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file, 'Opening'), pd.read_excel(file, 'Closing')]))`. If you have only either of them available, you could even change to

```
try:
     list_of_dfs.append(pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file, 'Opening'))
except:
     pass
try: 
     list_of_dfs.append(pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file, 'Closing'))
except:
     pass
```

(Of course, you should specify the exact error, but can't test that atm)

Comment: Great idea, i just tried it, but it yields the same error. I already changed the directory and file names, but the result is the same.

Comment: Are you using a Jupyter notebook, and not just the Anaconda console? You'll need to use the entire file path rather than the file name, because Anaconda is looking only at its current directory.

Comment: Also, if you want to specify the sheet of the workbook being read, and/or want to combine all sheets, you can do `list_of_dfs.append(pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file, 'Opening'), pd.read_excel(file, 'Closing')]))`

Comment: @jack6e I am using the spyder console.

Comment: @Roelant The second part works perfectly, but just following up, if I have some data from the sheet "closing" (some workbooks), and some data from sheet "opening" (other workbooks), while some workbooks have both and some have none, is there a way, during the "reading process" to combine those specifically? (I mean, opening with opening, closing with closing and so on).

Comment: Perfect :) Would be great if you could accept the answer then! And would it be ok to just append them separately to  a list_of_openings and list_of_closing? Then you can use pd.concat(list_of_openings) for all your opening sheets and vice versa

Comment: Yeah, that would be a good solution. But I don't know how to do it, hahaha. Anyway, I marked the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1: If you are using IDE or Jupyter put absolute path to file.
Or add the project folder to system path (workaround, not recommended).